Two updates to two tables
I have to update two tables
UPDATE TableA 
SET a = 'a', b = 'b', date = GETDATE() 
WHERE c = 'c'

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    INSERT INTO TableA (c, a, b, date) 
    VALUES ('c', 'a', 'b', GETDATE())

UPDATE TableB 
SET d = 'd', date = GETDATE() 
WHERE e = 'e' AND f = 'f' 

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    INSERT INTO TableB (e, f, d, date) 
    VALUES ('e', 'f', 'd', GETDATE())

They are about 10k rows in each of those tables and I need to perform this as fast as possible because the data will be updated 100x per second.
I thought about this
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE TableA
SET a = 'a', b = 'b', date = GETDATE()
WHERE c = 'c';

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableA (c, a, b, date)
    VALUES ('c', 'a', 'b', GETDATE());
END

UPDATE TableB
SET d = 'd', date = GETDATE()
WHERE e = 'e' AND f = 'f';

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableB (e, f, d, date)
    VALUES ('e', 'f', 'd', GETDATE());
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

But the thing is that the insert part will be executed only once for each device, the rest of the time it will be just updated. Is my method efficient? Perhaps I should prefill the table with initial values and omit the inserts in my operation?

Do you expect the number of rows to remain circa 10K forever? what percentage of that 10K would c='c' select (ie what percentage will you be updating)? Same question for TableB e='e' AND f='f'. Which of these columns (all you mentioned) are indexed?

If I understand you right you will have a lot more updates then you will have inserts, in that case it seems to me a correct aproach, considering all what you have show us

Yes, I expect it to remain about 10k forever. Eventually all those rows will be updated one by a time (in random order). There are no indexed columns.

Scanning a table of 10k rows should not to take the data engine very long, unless the server is very under speced, or there's a immense amount of contention. 10k rows is a tiny amount of data in the grand scheme of things. Of course, appropriate indexing might help speed up finding the rows to UPDATE.

if there are a lot of concurrent inserts/updates, you will have problems with the above code. What are you actually modelling? I agree about the prefilling!

If you want 10k forever then batch processing will be also helpful and if possible look for indexing on table A and B respectively
something like this...(i have added few columns,just add all columns and edit the query)

-- Create a temporary table for  updates and inserts
CREATE TABLE #TempUpdates (
     
    a NVARCHAR(255), 
    b NVARCHAR(255), 
     --add more columns like c,d,e,f stc
);

-- Insert data into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #TempUpdates ( a, b, c,..,..,)
VALUES
    (''a1', 'b1', ),
    ( 'a2', 'b2' ),
    ( 'a3', 'b3' );
 

-- Update TableA in batch
UPDATE a
SET a.a = t.a, a.b = t.b, a.date = GETDATE()
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN #TempUpdates AS t ON a.c = t.c;

-- Insert new rows into TableA
INSERT INTO TableA (c, a, b, date)
SELECT t.c, t.a, t.b, GETDATE()
FROM #TempUpdates AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA WHERE c = t.c);

-- Update TableB in batch
UPDATE b
SET b.d = t.d, b.date = GETDATE()
FROM TableB AS b
INNER JOIN #TempUpdates AS t ON b.e = t.e AND b.f = t.f;

-- Insert new rows into TableB
INSERT INTO TableB (e, f, d, date)
SELECT t.e, t.f, t.d, GETDATE()
FROM #TempUpdates AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB WHERE e = t.e AND f = t.f);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

 
DROP TABLE #TempUpdates;


The best way is either you prefill it with some initial values.
Or either you can merge it like.
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

MERGE TableA AS target
USING (VALUES ('c', 'a', 'b', GETDATE())) AS source(c, a, b, date)
ON target.c = source.c
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET a = source.a, b = source.b, date = source.date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (c, a, b, date) VALUES (source.c, source.a, source.b, source.date);

MERGE TableB AS target
USING (VALUES ('e', 'f', 'd', GETDATE())) AS source(e, f, d, date)
ON target.e = source.e AND target.f = source.f
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET d = source.d, date = source.date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (e, f, d, date) VALUES (source.e, source.f, source.d, source.date);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;


Merge is well known to have issues... manual update with insert if required (as OP is using) is typically better.

Yes Dale @ Dale K.. Merge May have some issues like concurrency,performance overhead etc, but it depends.We cant rule it out .Try once with your data @user3742046

Otherwise indexing or batch processing may also help and it will be a better approach I can say

So, you want to use MERGE, eh?
